# I am trying to use mlocate and for loops in bash to search for a multitude of files

Tags: linux, bash, loops, find, locate

So in bash, if I want I can simply do(where foo is a list of paths to files):

```
for i in `cat foo`; do ls -lah $i; done
```

I have a list of files I need to search for.  My thought is; why not run them through a for loop with mlocate?  I could do:

```
for i in `cat foo`; do locate $i; done
```

...but is that the best way to do what I'm trying to do?

Find is SLOW and takes forever when there are millions of files and directories whereas mlocate is super quick.

Answer (score 0):

If *files.txt* contains a list of *absolute paths* with a *newline line terminator* you can do this to *ensure they all exist:*

```
set -o errexit
mapfile -t < files.txt
for path in "${MAPFILE[@]}"
do
    [[ -e "$path" ]]
done
```

You can then expand on this if you want to do certain things with existing/non-existing files:

```
if [[ -e "$path" ]]
then
    …
else
    …
fi
```

If files.txt is so huge that the list does not fit in memory you *can* use a *much slower* `while read` loop:

```
while read -r -u 9 path
do
    [[ -e "$path" ]]
done 9< files.txt
```

If speed really is of the essence you probably want to do this in a different language, like Java or Rust.

On a technical note, `mlocate` is fast because it queries a pre-generated list of files on your system, but its database does not stay in sync with the actual filesystem contents automatically. Instead you need to run `updatedb` to populate the database with the current filesystem contents. This is usually done by a root cron job daily.

In terms of style, backticks are deprecated for `$(COMMAND)` and [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: yeah I know I could use other things, but was hoping to stay with mlocate.  I know updatedb would need to be run if I want to ensure search is truly up-to-date and we'd have a cron job nightly doing that.

Even running it manually it only takes about 30 seconds with TONS of files so it's not that hard to do.